# Error in line <context:component-scan="com.gontuseries.hellocontroller" />

Tags: spring, testing, model-view-controller

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  

<context:component-scan="com.gontuseries.hellocontroller" />


<bean id="viewResolver"
class= "org.springframework.web.servelet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name = "prefix">
<value>"/WEB-INF/"</value>
</property>
<property name = "suffix">
<value>"".jsp"</value>
</property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

I am making a test spring mvc program but I am getting error in line mentioned above. I have included all necessary files.

Comment: a cross on eclipse jee before this line saying any symbol or character missing

Comment: You are missing the `base-package` attribute. `<context:component-scan base-package="com.gontuseries.hellocontroller" />`.

Comment: I added base-package but still it is showing error.

Comment: "xsi:schemaLocation associated with element type "context" must be followed with a "=" charater" is what eclipse says now.